# Tailwind CSS EACCESS Error When Running Project In Node Docker Container (Docker Compose)

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, tailwind-css, sveltekit

I have a project that is using svelte-kit and Tailwind CSS. I recently moved it over to using docker compose. When I run my containers, I run them in WSL because they usually run better there. When I start the container that runs the development server, it starts up and runs just fine, but when I open the URL in my browser, I get the following error.

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.tailwindcss/touch'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1325:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/node_modules/tailwindcss/jit/lib/setupContext.js:44:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/node_modules/tailwindcss/jit/index.js:7:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
```

I'm unsure what's causing this error but I think it has something to do with tailwind.
Here is a link to my docker-compose file: https://github.com/DriedSponge/GorillianCurrencyConversion/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

If you want to try it out yourself, here is a link to the repo and the steps to reproduce:
https://github.com/DriedSponge/GorillianCurrencyConversion

Install Packages: `docker-compose run npm install`

Start Dev Server: `docker-compose --profile dev up -d --build`

Please let me know if you have any ideas on what's happening, or if you need any additional information from me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Tailwind is [trying to create a touch file](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/src/jit/lib/setupWatchingContext.js) which has something to do with watching for file changes during development, specifically when Tailwind is in [JIT mode](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#watch-mode-and-one-off-builds).

You might be able to fix this by either:

1. Allowing write access to `/root/.tailwindcss`.
2. Disabling touch by setting the `TAILWIND_DISABLE_TOUCH` environment variable.
3. Changing the touch file directory by setting the `TAILWIND_TOUCH_DIR` environment variable to a location where writing is allowed.

To set environment variables, it might be most convenient to set those in your `package.json` file. Simply add the environment variable in front of the relevant command under `scripts`, such as:

```
"dev": "TAILWIND_TOUCH_DIR='/var/www/html/.tailwindcss/touch' svelte-kit dev"
```

Be careful not to point this directory to one containing important files, since Tailwind will delete all the files inside that directory.

None of these options are documented anywhere except for [comments in the source](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/src/jit/lib/setupWatchingContext.js) so I'm not entirely sure what the consequences of this are, especially during development mode. I believe that this is used for communicating when files have changed, so option 1 or 3 might be the safest choices.